# What kind of skull is this - fish?

Tags: species-identification

Skull found near Merrimack River, West Newbury, MA frequented by Eagles, Hawks. Some kind of fish maybe? It's about the size of a hand

[image]

Comment: I'll leave answering to someone who can tell for certain, but it looks more pelvis-like than a skull to me.

Comment: that is not a skull, it is a weathered bird pelvis. but without scale and how heavily weathered it is picking an exact bird will be tricky. some bird pelvises for comparison https://ecuador.inaturalist.org/posts/27974-peacock-chicken-and-duck-pelvis-comparison

Comment: Wow! You guys are fantastic - I never would have thought pelvis. Thank you for the help. It's about the size of my hand, including the fingers. Probably duck since that's what's in the area. Thank you!